# Changing Back Colour Of Control In Another Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to understand how I can change the properties of a control in a different form.

I have a picturebox in form1 I want to change the back colour of, so here is the code I am using

**Form1**

```
    public PictureBox ThePicture
    {
        get { return this.pictureBox1; }
    }
```

Then in form2 I have

**Form2**

```
if (ScreenShot.saveToClipboard)
                {
                    Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();


                    ControlPanel form1 = new ControlPanel();

                    form1.ThePicture.BackColor = Color.Red;


                }
```

Nothing happens, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Don't use `new` to change property of *existing* form control.

Comment: Because you make a new `ControlPanel` it isn't the one that is already there

Comment: why not just set the backcolor in form1 after form2's work is done?  You could even create an event in form2 to change the backcolor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the reference of Form1 while initialising Form2. Then use this reference to make changes.

Form2 should have a Form1 property

```
public Form1 Form1Ref {get;set;}
```

Then:

```
// ... in Form1 ...
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Form1Ref = this; // reference to Form1
f2.Show();
```

Finally, over in Form2:

```
// ... in Form2 ...
this.Form1Ref.ThePicture.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Thanks, I get a red line on form1Instance

Comment: `form1Instance` needs initialization. `Form1 form1Instance = new Form1();`

Comment: Assuming you are creating Form2 from Form1, change `f2.Form1Ref = form1Instance;` to `f2.Form1Ref = this;`.  Then the last line will be `this.Form1Ref.ThePicture.BackColor = Color.Red;`...BUT that line would be used within Form2!